# How to redirect output of Ruby programme to some file

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
puts "amit"
puts "ravi"
```

It outputs:

```
amit
ravi
```

I would like to redirect *amit* to one file and *ravi* to a different file.

Suppose my file name is `name.rb`. When I am trying like

```
system("name.rb > #{@filename}")
```

both *amit* and *ravi* are redirected to @filename but I want redirection to a different file or first it will redirect to two files of same name but in one file output is *amit* and in other file of same output is *ravi*.

Comment: You can write to STDERR and STDOUT separately and then redirect each of these outputs to a different file on the command line.  However, I don't think there's a way to use output redirection on the command line to direct arbitrary STDOUT output to specific files.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the destination of $stdout and $stderr:

```
stout = File.open(ARGV[0], 'w')
sterr = File.open(ARGV[1], 'w')

$stdout.reopen(stout)
$stderr.reopen(sterr)

puts "something"
$stderr.puts "something another"
```

Comment: sir cud u plzz explain it more i m really strugglimg...
like if my o/p like that
setp viddec2   video_max_width   720
setp viddec2   video_display   on

setp viddec2   video_max_width   720
setp viddec2   video_display   off
how to i redirect 
two parts of my o/p seprated my newlines to two differnt files plzzz
sir help me or anyone else knows 
first part of o/p means 
setp viddec2   video_max_width   720
setp viddec2   video_display   on  
generated by one loop and second part by other loop and suppose my filename is main.rb and i m doing system("filee.rb > #{@filename}")

Comment: i am able to redirect whole o/p to @filename but i want first part of o/p to be redirected to one file and other part o/p to some other file system("main.rb > #{@filename}") that i m doing

Comment: nd how in my case i can change destination of $stdout

Comment: The $stdout destination change is in line 4. You must call reopen() func on it. (Sorry for late answer)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of redirecting you can pass filenames as arguments and write from ruby to the files:

```
open(ARGV[0], 'w') do |f|
  f.puts "amit"
end

open(ARGV[1], 'w') do |f|
  f.puts "ravi"
end
```

Then:

```
system("name.rb 1.txt 2.txt")
```

Comment: sorry leventix i did not get you cud u expain it more

Comment: nd suppose and very big means its of many line then what to do??

Comment: This solution is applicable if you can modify the file that writes the text. If this is the case you should modify that program to output each line to the file you want.

If you explain what you want to achieve, maybe we can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Ruby Input/Output](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_input_output.htm) and [Ruby File Handling](http://www.meshplex.org/wiki/Ruby/File_handling_Input_Output).

Comment: sir is it possible to redirect different parts of the output to be redirect to differnt file or to same like amit to some file and ravi to different

Comment: I do not think that one can "split" the ouput of a program and redirect it to different files unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, so here some keywords that might do it:

- consider two ouput methods: `STDOUT` and `STDERR`

- if you work with unix and/or can not modify the ruby program itself, the following tools might be helpful: sed, awk, grep.